# Scene rendering wonky when camera transformations occur

Tags: c++, matrix, camera, transformation, glm-math

I've recently switched over to GLM for managing my matrices and vectors, however when I change my variables such as camera angles or position, the whole rendered scene goes haywire.

I really don't know how to describe it other than stretching and moving all over the place.

**Problem:**

- "Camera" transformations such as panning the camera result in strange atypical/unexpected changes. Typically, when the camera pan variables like X and Y deviate from "0"

**Note:**

- I used to perform these very same types of transformations on Qt's datatypes for QMatrix4x4 and QVector3D, rather than glm::mat4x4 and glm::vec4, ***and it worked fine***

Here is the way I'm implementing the camera in my render function (alpha and beta are rotation vars, and = 0 by default, camX and camY are panning vars, and also = 0 by default):

```
glm::mat4x4 mMatrix;
glm::mat4x4 vMatrix;

glm::mat4x4 cameraTransformation;
cameraTransformation = glm::rotate(cameraTransformation, glm::radians(alpha)/*alpha*(float)M_PI/180*/, glm::vec3(0, 1 ,0));
cameraTransformation = glm::rotate(cameraTransformation, glm::radians(beta)/*beta*(float)M_PI/180*/, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));

glm::vec4 cameraPosition = (cameraTransformation * glm::vec4(camX, camY, distance, 0));
glm::vec4 cameraUpDirection = cameraTransformation * glm::vec4(0, 1, 0, 0);

vMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(cameraPosition[0],cameraPosition[1],cameraPosition[2]), glm::vec3(camX, camY, 0.0), glm::vec3(cameraUpDirection[0],cameraUpDirection[1],cameraUpDirection[2]));

glm::mat4x4 glmat = pMatrix * vMatrix * mMatrix;
QMatrix4x4 qmat = QMatrix4x4(glmat[0][0],glmat[0][1],glmat[0][2],glmat[0][3],
                             glmat[1][0],glmat[1][1],glmat[1][2],glmat[1][3],
                             glmat[2][0],glmat[2][1],glmat[2][2],glmat[2][3],
                             glmat[3][0],glmat[3][1],glmat[3][2],glmat[3][3]);
shaderProgram.bind();
shaderProgram.setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", qmat);
```

I set up my projection matrix as so (fov = 30 degrees):

```
pMatrix = glm::perspective( glm::radians(fov), (float)width/(float)height, (float)0.001, (float)10000 );
```

My matrices look like this at the time they are used:
[image: matrices]

Here's an example of how it looks

Before any changes, all values are at 0:
[image: example1]

When camX changes to 14 (note, I **didn't** rotate my camera around!):
[image: example2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glm::mat4x4 cameraTransformation;
cameraTransformation = glm::rotate(cameraTransformation, glm::radians(alpha)/*alpha*(float)M_PI/180*/, glm::vec3(0, 1 ,0));
cameraTransformation = glm::rotate(cameraTransformation, glm::radians(beta)/*beta*(float)M_PI/180*/, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
```

This can be simplified by using matrix multiplication and using a different glm call:

```
glm::mat4x4 cameraTransformation =
glm::rotate(glm::radians(alpha), glm::vec3(0,1,0)) *
glm::rotate(glm::radians(beta), glm::vec3(1,0,0));
```

Next:

```
glm::vec4 cameraPosition = (cameraTransformation * glm::vec4(camX, camY, distance, 0));
glm::vec4 cameraUpDirection = cameraTransformation * glm::vec4(0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Having a zero in the `w` component of a vector indicates that the vector is a direction, not a position. Yet you are obtaining a position vector as the output. This happens to work because `cameraTransformation` has only rotation operations, not translating operations, but it's better to be clear:

```
glm::vec3 cameraPosition = glm::vec3(cameraTransformation * glm::vec4(camX, camY, distance, 1));
```

Note- I use a vec3 not a vec4 because I just like to do that.

For the next part you actually do want a direction vector and not a position vector, so you should have a zero in the `w` component. Still cast it to a vec3, because it's just clearer in my opinion.

```
glm::vec3 cameraUpDirection = glm::vec3(cameraTransformation * glm::vec4(0, 1, 0, 0));
```

Next:

```
vMatrix=
glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(cameraPosition[0],cameraPosition[1],cameraPosition[2]),
glm::vec3(camX, camY, 0.0),
glm::vec3(cameraUpDirection[0],cameraUpDirection[1],cameraUpDirection[2]));
```

Glm lets you pass a `vec3` into a `vec4` as a constructor parameter so you can shorten your code like this:

```
vMatrix=
glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(cameraPosition),
glm::vec3(camX, camY, 0.0),
glm::vec3(cameraUpDirection));
```

But we don't even need to do that because i changed the variables into `vec3`s not `vec4`s:

```
vMatrix= glm::lookAt(cameraPosition, glm::vec3(camX, camY, 0.0), cameraUpDirection);
```

And finally, you can access the components of a `glm` vector using `.x`,`.y`,`.z`,`.w` instead of the `[]` operator, which I imagine is much safer and easier to read.

Comment: @Yattabyte You may have to include some other header to get it to work, but you don't need to use the same function i did, I just think it's a little easier. Just out of curiosity, your camera code worked fully before? As in, you could rotate and translate and it would function as expected?

Comment: Yeah it did. As long as I applied the fix I mentioned in my own answer.
Well, it mostly worked. It had some strange orbiting, but I constrained how far it could rotate before I ever get that effect anyway

Comment: I didn't realize I could change my vector4 to vector3's by doing it like that. Thank you, it definitely is a lot neater now!

Comment: @Yattabyte I'm glad I could help, glm is a really well designed library. Honestly your code looks really weird though, like, you rotate your camera position about it's angle, then you do a `lookAt` from that point to `<camX, camY, 0>` which doesn't make any sense, but hey, if it works.

Comment: Lol yeah, I'm still trying to learn all this 3D stuff. Most of my rendering code was based off of old tutorials - those lines probably aren't the only redundant thing in my code

Answer (score 0):

I made a very stupid error!

In attempt to convert my glm::mat4x4 to QMatrix4x4, I accidentally swapped the rows and columns.

I needed to change:

```
QMatrix4x4 qmat = QMatrix4x4(glmat[0][0],glmat[0][1],glmat[0][2],glmat[0][3],
                             glmat[1][0],glmat[1][1],glmat[1][2],glmat[1][3],
                             glmat[2][0],glmat[2][1],glmat[2][2],glmat[2][3],
                             glmat[3][0],glmat[3][1],glmat[3][2],glmat[3][3]);
```

to:

```
QMatrix4x4 qmat = QMatrix4x4(glmat[0][0],glmat[1][0],glmat[2][0],glmat[3][0],
                             glmat[0][1],glmat[1][1],glmat[2][1],glmat[3][1],
                             glmat[0][2],glmat[1][2],glmat[2][2],glmat[3][2],
                             glmat[0][3],glmat[1][3],glmat[2][3],glmat[3][3]);
```

Comment: You've got a load of other problems too :P

Comment: If you meant the formatting in the question, somehow the arrays changed numbers, I fixed that (the [#] is the same tag used on this site for external url quoting, so it changed them for some reason). Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Well, your code could be a lot shorter because of some glm things, which I'll show you, and your matrix math is a bit off. I'll make an answer.